# Eclipse error when trying to run C code

Tags: c, eclipse

I'm trying to understand binary and hexadecimal numbers. I want to know why my program won't launch in eclipse. It gives me this error:

```
launch has encountered a problem
```

It was running when i used `int`. My computer is 64bit. I'm trying to understand hardware. I need to know what I'm doing wrong. What can I improve on? Is it okay to declare buffer as a global variable? Thanks.

My code is here.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
char * convertBase(unsigned long int numberToConvert, long int base)
{

    char buffer[65];
    char *pConvertedNumber;
    char allValues[] = "0123456789abcdef";

    pConvertedNumber = &buffer[sizeof(buffer)-1];

    *pConvertedNumber = '\0';

    do {

        int value = numberToConvert % base;

        pConvertedNumber = pConvertedNumber - 1;

        *pConvertedNumber = allValues[value];

        numberToConvert /= base;

    } while(numberToConvert != 0);

    printf("%s", pConvertedNumber);

    return pConvertedNumber;
}

int main(void){

    unsigned long int numberOne = 1000000000;
    printf("\n%ld in Base 16 = ", numberOne);
    convertBase(numberOne, 16);

    printf("\n");

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code is fine. The problem you are having is probably caused by eclipse.

Comment: note : `return pConvertedNumber;` return pointer point to local object.

Comment: ^^ yeah, I noticed that, but not used here. Still...

Comment: 'okay to declare buffer as a global variable?' - well sort of.  It would be better if the conversion function took a buffer pointer, (and perhaps a length limit), as a parameter.  If nothing else, it would then be reentrant and thread-safe.

Comment: Just to make sure, declare convertBase as void and do not try to return pConvertNumber. Also make the application by hand rather than in eclipse. This will let you see if it is eclipse itself that is causing the problem.

Comment: When you get it launched, it fills the buffer from the end backwards, so leaving the start of the buffer uninitialized?

Comment: Your code is *not* "fine". You're returning an address within an automatic variable that ceases to exist once your function returns. In doing so, the caller receivers an invalid pointer, and any attempts to dereference it invoke *undefined behavior*. You're not using this address, but I can't imagine that will last long. You also aren't terminating your buffer. Pass the buffer address and size from the caller. Fill from offset-0 forward, laying the chars in *reverse* order. Once completed with the conversion, reverse the string of chars you just created, properly terminate, and you're done.

Comment: @WhozCraig do you mind assisting me on that? thanks.

Comment: @MadonahSyombua One way of *many, many* different algorithms would be [something like this](http://ideone.com/V73rOz). Untested beyond that harness, but its pretty close to what I was describing.

Comment: You can do it recursively and so avoid reversing the output string.

Comment: I edited the code to show that it is more general and to simplify the base 8, 10, and 16 bases with sprintf. I changed the example to base 12 and added an error check for an invalid base.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively you can use sprintf(buffer, "%x", numbertoConvert) where the base is 16. However, if the base is not octal or hex then the following routine would work.

**EDIT** Note that this is restricted to bases less than 16, with the ABCDF definitions being the same as with hexadecimal (base can be 11, 12, 13, 14, or 15). The conversion still comes out correctly.

**EDIT** I can also change the list of base characters to an array of strings and use strcat, but I will leave that up to you.
    allValues[] = { "0", "1", ... }
    strcat(buffer, allValues[value]);

You are trying to print a buffer (as %s) without any '\0' which means that it is not terminated. The code should be

```
size_t processBase(int numberToConvert, int base, char* mybuffer)
  {
    size_t mysize = 0;
    mybuffer[0] = '\0';
    if (base > 16 || base < 2)
    {
      printf("Invalid base specified\n");
      return mysize;
    }
    switch(base)
    {
      case 16:
      {
        sprintf(mybuffer, "%#x", numberToConvert);
        break;
      }
      case 8:
      {
        sprintf(mybuffer, "%#o", numberToConvert);
        break;
      }
      case 10:
      {
        sprintf(mybuffer, "%d", numberToConvert);
        break;
      }
      default:
      {
        convertBase(numberToConvert, base, mybuffer);
        break;
      }
    }

    printf("%s\n", mybuffer);
    mysize = strlen(mybuffer);
    return mysize;
  }

void convertBase(int numbertoConvert, int base, char *rbuffer)
{
  char buffer[65];
  char *pConvertedNumber;
  char allValues[] = "0123456789abcdef";
  size_t mysize;

  buffer[0] = '\0'; // This initializes the buffer
  pConvertedNumber = &buffer;
  do {

      int value = numberToConvert % base;

      *pConvertedNumber = allValues[value];
      pconvertedNumber += 1;
      *pconvertedNumber = '\0';

      numberToConvert /= base;

  } while(numberToConvert != 0);

  mysize = strlen(buffer);  // This shows the number of characters
  for (int i = 1; i <= mysize; i++)
    {
       rbuffer[mysize-i] = buffer[i-1];
    }
  rbuffer[mysize] = '\0';
}

int main(void)
{
  unsigned long int numberOne = 1000000000;
  int base = 12
  mybuffer[65];
  printf("\n%ld in Base %d = ", numberOne, base);
  size_t mysize = processBase(numberOne, base, mybuffer);

  printf("Has %d characters\n", mysize);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

..or without the string reversal, and with the caller supplying the buffer:

```
 #include <stdio.h>

const char* hexlat="0123456789ABCDEF";

char * convertBase(unsigned long int numberToConvert, int base, char *output){
  if(numberToConvert>base) output=convertBase(numberToConvert/base,base,output);
  *output=hexlat[numberToConvert % base];
  return output+1;
};

int main(void) {
    unsigned int numToConvert=1000000000;
    char ascResult[64];
    *convertBase(numToConvert,16,ascResult)='\0';
    printf("%s",ascResult);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You still need to add the '\0' to the end of the output buffer. Also can use a buffer of string characters and use strcat.