# C - program crashes after free() is called

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, free

I've been exercising and experimenting around lately with pointers, bitwise operations, malloc, etc. while following a tutorial and encountered a crash that I do not know how to fix (without removing free()).

The tutorial code is the same as mine with the exact same free() function and for them it works.

This is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

char *convertBase(unsigned int InNumber, int base, char *pConvertedNumber){

    char hexVal[]="0123456789ABCDEF";

        if(base<2 || base>16){
            printf("Enter a base between 2 and 16");
            exit(1);
        }

    *pConvertedNumber = '\0';

    do{

        int value = InNumber % base;

        pConvertedNumber = pConvertedNumber - 1;

        *pConvertedNumber = hexVal[value];

        InNumber/=base;

    }while(InNumber !=0);

    return pConvertedNumber;

}

void main(){

    unsigned int six = 6;
    unsigned int seven = 7;

    char *pConvertedNumber;
    pConvertedNumber = malloc(33 * sizeof(char));

    unsigned int AND = six & seven;

    printf("%s & ", convertBase(six, 2, pConvertedNumber));
    printf("%s = ", convertBase(seven, 2, pConvertedNumber));
    printf("%s \n\n", convertBase(AND, 2, pConvertedNumber));

    free(pConvertedNumber);
}
```

Comment: `pConvertedNumber = pConvertedNumber - 1;` are you sure?

Comment: also, you don;t seem to null-termnate before return.

Comment: @SouravGhosh I think it is null-termintaed before the `do` loop.

Comment: @MikeCAT that's the problem. putt null in valid position and then, go out of bound. :) There's no proper null-termination.

Comment: Here's [another question with the same convertBase code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31777425/eclipse-error-when-trying-to-run-c-code). But I'm not inclined to mark-duplicate because the answer here solves the problem in the code whereas the answers in the other one give alternative approaches.

Comment: You'll want to add a special case for 0.  Currently an empty string is printed for 0.

Comment: `void main()` is an invalid signature and results in undefined behaviour. Use the correct one and use prototype-style declarators.

Answer (score 4):

You invoked *undefined behavior* by moving pointer to out-of-range at the line

```
pConvertedNumber = pConvertedNumber - 1;
```

Try changing three `pConvertedNumber` that are passed to `convertBase` to `pConvertedNumber + 32` so that the pointer aritimetic won't go out-of-range.

Also note that you should use standard `int main(void)` in hosted environment instead of `void main()`, which is illegal in C89 and implementation-defined in C99 or later, unless you have some special reason to use non-standard signature.